# Long post fails to render

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

In [one MathOverflow answer by me](https://mathoverflow.net/a/429455/352898), the MathJax code added latest fails to render correctly. Instead, one `$` tag is ignored and for the rest on the line, code inside `$` tags is rendered as if outside `$` tags and text outside `$` tags is rendered as if inside `$` tags. Is it because the post is too long or contains too much MathJax code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it was just an oversight - unpaired curly brackets.

Putting `$V_{i(g)(\kappa)}^M=V_{i(g)(\kappa)}^N$` $V_{i(g)(\kappa)}^M=V_{i(g)(\kappa)}^N$ works as expected, `$V_{i(g)(\kappa)^M=V_{i(g)(\kappa)^N$` does not render: $V_{i(g)(\kappa)^M=V_{i(g)(\kappa)^N$.

I have [edited the post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/429455/revisions) - I hope I haven't overlooked some other problem. You can compare [revision 4](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/429455/4) (your version) with [revision 5](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/429455/5) (my edit). Revisions 4 contained: `and since $V_{i(g)(\kappa)^M=V_{i(g)(\kappa)^N$, $\kappa$ is $i(f)(\kappa)$-extendible in $M$`.

As a side note, when somebody runs into problems with MathJax when posting or editing, they could try asking in the [MO editor's lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/10243/mo-editors-lounge) or in the [Mathjax chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13752/mathjax). However, both of those rooms are visited only by a few users - so on meta, such question will get noticed faster (and it will get more eyes on it).

Comment: Thank you. I found another place where I forgot a bracket.